# How can I split a list of comma separated words in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I was querying Stackoverflow to get some data (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), and I have a data frame with Tags as a column. The tags originally were of the form

```
<html><css>
```

I managed to get them in the form of

```
html,css
```

I think an image of my Jupyter notebook can display it best:
[image: Jupyter notebook row]

How can I separate the tags so that they can become categorical variables, and I can transform them using something like get_dummies?
Everything I've seen refers to actual lists, like [html,css], rather than just comma separated words.

Comment: i was writing up an answer to your histogram question, but then it got closed/deleted. try removing the last line `df.plot(...)` and using this instead: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6)); ax.bar(df.index, df['OccurDate'], width=20); ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%B'))` (pandas plots do not play well with dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, we can use `df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(',')`, which basically performs `split` and converts each element to its own one-hot encoded column.